# HttpContext.Current is null When Using Google Chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 application and have the following code that I placed inside my `DbContextInitializer` class' `Seed()` method.

```
string filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + file);
```

The problem is, whenever I run my ASP.NET MVC in Google Chrome, `HttpContext.Current` is `null` causing  `NullReferenceException` when the `Seed()` method is called. I have tried Internet Explorer and Fire Fox and the error does not occur. I even tried Google Chrome in Incognito mode but the error still occurs. Do you guys have any idea about what could be causing this error? Thanks in advance.

Update:
When using Google Chrome, the `Seed()` method is immediately executed once I run my web application even on the home page which should not execute since there is no query to database yet. IE and Fire Fox does not have this behavior.

Comment: I think the two are unrelated. Have you put a brakpoint directly within your controller action and looked to see what HttpContext is there from Chrome? The requesting browser is just a user agent to the server...

Comment: I have put a break point and it shows that the `Current` of `HttpContext` property is null. I have added more information on my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
string filePath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Images/" + file);
```

This way you're not gonna get NREs in methods and threads that are deprived of any HttpContext.

As far as why HttpContext.Current is null, well, there might be lots of reasons. Your code is running in the initialization of the web application and your application is using integrated pipeline mode or for example you are running the code in a separate thread in which there's no context at all.

Conclusion: stay away from `HttpContext.Current`. Every time you are using it you should be asking yourself if there isn't a better way to achieve whatever you are trying to achieve. And there always is.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer code works although I am still wondering why Chrome is behaving differently than other browsers.